# Error using static library with iOS 7 or higher

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I have an example project that include an static library called "libReaderFramework.a" which compile and run perfect when the master project (the project which include the static library) has a target iOS 6 or lower. But if I put the target to iOS 7 or higher this errors occurs:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::_List_node_base::hook(std::_List_node_base*)", referenced from:
      std::list<uft::Value*, std::allocator<uft::Value*> >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<uft::Value*>, uft::Value* const&) in libReaderFramework.a(xpath_yacc.o)
  "std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::vector<empdf::PDFDocument::pdfPageCacheEntry, std::allocator<empdf::PDFDocument::pdfPageCacheEntry> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<empdf::PDFDocument::pdfPageCacheEntry*, std::vector<empdf::PDFDocument::pdfPageCacheEntry, std::allocator<empdf::PDFDocument::pdfPageCacheEntry> > >, empdf::PDFDocument::pdfPageCacheEntry const&) in libReaderFramework.a(embed_pdf_t3.o)
      std::deque<mdom::Node, std::allocator<mdom::Node> >::_M_new_elements_at_back(unsigned long) in libReaderFramework.a(xpath_context.o)
      std::deque<mdom::Node, std::allocator<mdom::Node> >::_M_new_elements_at_front(unsigned long) in libReaderFramework.a(xpath_context.o)
      std::vector<empdf::CLayout::OpacityInfoRec, std::allocator<empdf::CLayout::OpacityInfoRec> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<empdf::CLayout::OpacityInfoRec*, std::vector<empdf::CLayout::OpacityInfoRec, std::allocator<empdf::CLayout::OpacityInfoRec> > >, empdf::CLayout::OpacityInfoRec const&) in libReaderFramework.a(embed_pdf_t3_layout.o)
      std::vector<layout::AreaTreeNode*, std::allocator<layout::AreaTreeNode*> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<layout::AreaTreeNode**, std::vector<layout::AreaTreeNode*, std::allocator<layout::AreaTreeNode*> > >, layout::AreaTreeNode* const&) in libReaderFramework.a(layout_block.o)
      std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) in libReaderFramework.a(layout_block.o)
  "std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<tetraphilia::pdf::store::DictionaryKey const, unsigned long> >::operator++() in libReaderFramework.a(embed_pdf_t3.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >::operator++() in libReaderFramework.a(xpath_context.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::vector<layout::AreaTreeNode*, std::allocator<layout::AreaTreeNode*> > > >::operator++(int) in libReaderFramework.a(layout_block.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::vector<layout::AreaTreeNode*, std::allocator<layout::AreaTreeNode*> > > >::operator++() in libReaderFramework.a(layout_block.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<layout::ContainerNode* const, layout::AbsoluteVector<layout::AbsoluteItemInfo> > >::operator++(int) in libReaderFramework.a(layout_block.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<layout::ContainerNode* const, layout::AbsoluteVector<layout::AbsoluteItemInfo> > >::operator++() in libReaderFramework.a(layout_block.o)
  "std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<tetraphilia::pdf::store::DictionaryKey const, unsigned long> >::operator--() in libReaderFramework.a(embed_pdf_t3.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >::operator--() in libReaderFramework.a(xpath_context.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::vector<layout::AreaTreeNode*, std::allocator<layout::AreaTreeNode*> > > >::operator--() in libReaderFramework.a(layout_block.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<layout::ContainerNode* const, layout::AbsoluteVector<layout::AbsoluteItemInfo> > >::operator--() in libReaderFramework.a(layout_block.o)
  "std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree<tetraphilia::pdf::store::DictionaryKey, std::pair<tetraphilia::pdf::store::DictionaryKey const, unsigned long>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<tetraphilia::pdf::store::DictionaryKey const, unsigned long> >, tetraphilia::pdf::store::DictionaryKeyOrdering, std::allocator<std::pair<tetraphilia::pdf::store::DictionaryKey const, unsigned long> > >::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair<tetraphilia::pdf::store::DictionaryKey const, unsigned long> const&) in libReaderFramework.a(embed_pdf_t3.o)
      std::_Rb_tree<uft::Value, std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >, xpath::Context::ValueCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> > >::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> const&) in libReaderFramework.a(xpath_context.o)
      std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, std::vector<layout::AreaTreeNode*, std::allocator<layout::AreaTreeNode*> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, std::vector<layout::AreaTreeNode*, std::allocator<layout::AreaTreeNode*> > > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::vector<layout::AreaTreeNode*, std::allocator<layout::AreaTreeNode*> > > > >::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair<int const, std::vector<layout::AreaTreeNode*, std::allocator<layout::AreaTreeNode*> > > const&) in libReaderFramework.a(layout_block.o)
      std::_Rb_tree<layout::ContainerNode*, std::pair<layout::ContainerNode* const, layout::AbsoluteVector<layout::AbsoluteItemInfo> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<layout::ContainerNode* const, layout::AbsoluteVector<layout::AbsoluteItemInfo> > >, std::less<layout::ContainerNode*>, std::allocator<std::pair<layout::ContainerNode* const, layout::AbsoluteVector<layout::AbsoluteItemInfo> > > >::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair<layout::ContainerNode* const, layout::AbsoluteVector<layout::AbsoluteItemInfo> > const&) in libReaderFramework.a(layout_block.o)
  "std::string::append(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) in libReaderFramework.a(curlnetprovider.o)
  "std::string::append(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) in libReaderFramework.a(curlnetprovider.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()", referenced from:
      DLProxyInfo::DLProxyInfo(DLProxyInfo const&) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
      DLProxySettingsController::getSystemProxySettings() in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxySettingsController.o)
  "std::string::empty() const", referenced from:
      NSStringFromString(std::string const&) in libReaderFramework.a(DLHelpers.o)
      CurlStream::CurlStream(dp::String const&, dp::String const&, dpio::StreamClient*, dpio::Stream*, bool) in libReaderFramework.a(curlnetprovider.o)
      DLProxySettingsController::getSystemProxySettings() in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxySettingsController.o)
      DLProxySettingsController::updateProxyCredentials(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxySettingsController.o)
  "std::allocator<char>::allocator()", referenced from:
      GetStringFromCFString(__CFString const*) in libReaderFramework.a(DLHelpers.o)
      StringFromNSString(NSString*) in libReaderFramework.a(DLHelpers.o)
      DLProxyInfo::DLProxyInfo() in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
      DLProxyInfo::DLProxyInfo(std::string const&, int, bool, std::string const&, std::string const&, bool) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      GetStringFromCFString(__CFString const*) in libReaderFramework.a(DLHelpers.o)
      StringFromNSString(NSString*) in libReaderFramework.a(DLHelpers.o)
      DLProxyInfo::DLProxyInfo() in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
      DLProxyInfo::DLProxyInfo(std::string const&, int, bool, std::string const&, std::string const&, bool) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      DLProxyInfo::DLProxyInfo(std::string const&, int, bool, std::string const&, std::string const&, bool) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
      DLProxyInfo::getHostName() in libReaderFramework.a(curlnetprovider.o)
      DLProxyInfo::getUsername() in libReaderFramework.a(curlnetprovider.o)
      DLProxyInfo::getPassword() in libReaderFramework.a(curlnetprovider.o)
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) in libReaderFramework.a(curlnetprovider.o)
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) in libReaderFramework.a(curlnetprovider.o)
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(RMDocumentHost.o)
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(DLNetworkProxySettings.o)
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(DLHelpers.o)
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxySupport.o)
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(curlnetprovider.o)
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxySettingsController.o)
      ...
  "std::string::operator=(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      GetStringFromCFString(__CFString const*) in libReaderFramework.a(DLHelpers.o)
      DLProxyInfo::setHostName(std::string const&) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
      DLProxyInfo::setAutoURL(std::string const&) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
      DLProxyInfo::setUsername(std::string const&) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
      DLProxyInfo::setPassword(std::string const&) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
      GetProxyUserCredentials(std::string const&, std::string&, std::string&) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyCredentialStorage.o)
  "std::allocator<char>::~allocator()", referenced from:
      GetStringFromCFString(__CFString const*) in libReaderFramework.a(DLHelpers.o)
      StringFromNSString(NSString*) in libReaderFramework.a(DLHelpers.o)
      DLProxyInfo::DLProxyInfo() in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
      DLProxyInfo::DLProxyInfo(std::string const&, int, bool, std::string const&, std::string const&, bool) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      RMDocumentHostImpl::reportLoadingState(int) in libReaderFramework.a(RMDocumentHost.o)
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      RMDocumentHostImpl::reportLoadingState(int) in libReaderFramework.a(RMDocumentHost.o)
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(RMDocumentHost.o)
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(DLNetworkProxySettings.o)
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(DLHelpers.o)
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxySupport.o)
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(curlnetprovider.o)
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxySettingsController.o)
      ...
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      +[DLNetworkProxySettings systemProxySettings] in libReaderFramework.a(DLNetworkProxySettings.o)
      +[DLNetworkProxySettings authenticationInfoAvailable] in libReaderFramework.a(DLNetworkProxySettings.o)
      +[DLNetworkProxySettings saveProxyCredentials:] in libReaderFramework.a(DLNetworkProxySettings.o)
      +[DLNetworkProxySettings clearProxyCredentials:] in libReaderFramework.a(DLNetworkProxySettings.o)
      GetStringFromCFString(__CFString const*) in libReaderFramework.a(DLHelpers.o)
      UpdateSystemProxyCredentials(DLProxyInfo) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxySupport.o)
      DLProxyInfo::DLProxyInfo() in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyInfo.o)
      ...
  "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
      NSStringFromString(std::string const&) in libReaderFramework.a(DLHelpers.o)
      CurlStream::CurlStream(dp::String const&, dp::String const&, dpio::StreamClient*, dpio::Stream*, bool) in libReaderFramework.a(curlnetprovider.o)
      GetProxyUserCredentials(std::string const&, std::string&, std::string&) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyCredentialStorage.o)
      SaveProxyUserCredentials(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyCredentialStorage.o)
      ClearProxyUserCredentials(std::string const&) in libReaderFramework.a(DLProxyCredentialStorage.o)
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      RMDocumentHostImpl::reportLoadingState(int) in libReaderFramework.a(RMDocumentHost.o)
  "std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree<uft::Value, std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >, xpath::Context::ValueCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> > >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >) in libReaderFramework.a(xpath_context.o)
      std::_Rb_tree<layout::ContainerNode*, std::pair<layout::ContainerNode* const, layout::AbsoluteVector<layout::AbsoluteItemInfo> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<layout::ContainerNode* const, layout::AbsoluteVector<layout::AbsoluteItemInfo> > >, std::less<layout::ContainerNode*>, std::allocator<std::pair<layout::ContainerNode* const, layout::AbsoluteVector<layout::AbsoluteItemInfo> > > >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<layout::ContainerNode* const, layout::AbsoluteVector<layout::AbsoluteItemInfo> > >) in libReaderFramework.a(layout_block.o)
  "std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))", referenced from:
      RMDocumentHostImpl::reportLoadingState(int) in libReaderFramework.a(RMDocumentHost.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have the code of that static library and also I generate it, but I don't know why I must have a target iOS 6 or lower to use the static library. (I have the static library as a sub project of the main project)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if libReaderFramework.a is built to use libstdc++ as its standard C++ library.  When you build your main project, the choice of standard library probably defaults to libc++ for newer targets.

You should make a consistent choice of which to use.

(It is possible to link against both, but it's annoying and fragile.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Do you have and idea how to do that? show I change the libstdc++?

Comment: If it's all under your control, then I suggest moving everything to libc++ as the standard for both the .a and the main project.  (Unless you have to support Xcode versions that are too old and, in that case, you might need to create different .a files.)  If you use "std" to filter your build settings, you should see where the standard library is selected.

Comment: Yes it is under my control, I will change it now and I'll let you know

Comment: That's odd.  Those are libstdc++ symbols and if you're building your .a file to use a different standard, I can't think where they'd come from.  Try deleting derived data for the static library before building, maybe?

Comment: How could I delete derived data? by cleaning the app?

Comment: It's a button on the Organizer window next to the project.